# How to store user session in secha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Im using Sencha Touch 2 where i have a login form asking for username and password
now i want to store user details via Session/Cookie so the user can logout,

i browsed some links which i got

[Sencha-touch : save login / password (save session, multi-tasks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186269/sencha-touch-save-login-password-save-session-multi-tasks)

but im being an new to sench touch develpment

any help using code examples will be of very great input for me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something which is managed by the server, not the client, so you want to look at  , not at sencha itself.

On a guess that you are using php, for something really basic, take a look at:
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML5 localStore object. For instance, when a user logs in and your server request is made, on the callback of a successful server request you can store any necessary data. Here is a snippet from one of my apps:

```
loginCallback: function(options, success, response) {
        this.mainSplash.setMasked(false);
        var responseOjbect = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        if (responseOjbect.success) {
            this.clearLoginStorage(); //runs a function to clear some login storage values
            if (rememberme) {               
                localStorage.setItem("rememberme", 1);              
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("rememberme", 0);
            }   
            localStorage.setItem("userid", responseOjbect.userid);
            localStorage.setItem("first_name", responseOjbect.first_name);
            localStorage.setItem("last_name", responseOjbect.last_name);
            localStorage.setItem("appsettingone", responseOjbect.appsettingone);
            localStorage.setItem("appsettingtwo", responseOjbect.appsettingtwo);
            localStorage.setItem("setdate",  new Date());

            if (!this.dashboard) {
                Ext.create('myApp.view.Dashboard', {
                    //additional config
                });
            }
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.dashboard);
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Attention', responseOjbect.errorMessage, Ext.emptyFn);
        }
    }
```

Once you have set your localStorage items, they can be retrieved or removed like so:

```
localStorage.getItem("user_id"); //retrieve
localStorage.removeItem("userid"); //remove
```

So when you call your logout function, just don't remove any localStorage objects you want to keep. Then you can call localStorage.getItem("VALUE") to retrieve them upon next login

Comment: hi jeffery i made use of localStorage but no success -- my code localStorage.setItem("uid", "A");
     localStorage.setItem("password", "B"); 
     
     var ss =localStorage.getItem("uid"); 
     console.log(retJson.password);

Comment: Same code works for me if i console.log your ss variable... maybe viewing the guide on HTML5 storage will help